# 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainTabController' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, nsbundle

the error I'm receiving that I can't seem to fix is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named 'MainTabController' in bundle NSBundle

the app will build and the login screen will display but crashes immediately after with the error stated above.

I have tried all of the following from other post similar to this and have had no luck.

1. Removing the reference to the storyboard in the info.plist file. When I do this the app does start but I get a black screen as it doesn't load the storyboard.
2. Fiddle with the Target Membership Main.storyboard.
3. Remove the storyboard from the project, clean, run and then adding the storyboard back again.
4. Uninstall Xcode, reinstall Xcode.
5. Deleting the Derived Data folder.

the problem appears to be with my ***presentMainScreen()*** method

```
func presentMainScreen(){
     let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabController", bundle: nil)
      let mainTabController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
        mainTabController.selectedViewController = mainTabController.viewControllers?[1]
        //let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        //let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        //self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

if I comment out the mainTabController lines the app will work perfectly, also if I uncomment the loggedInVC lines and with the mainTabController lines commented out it works perfectly as well.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

below is my entire ***ViewController.swift*** code and a screenshot of my workspace

[workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ySy.png)

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            print("success")

          self.presentMainScreen()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func creatAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {



        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{ user, error in
                if let firebaseError = error {
                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                return
                }
                print("success")
               self.presentMainScreen()

        })

    }
}

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {



if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let firebaseError = error {
            print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
            return
         }

       print("success")

      self.presentMainScreen()

    })

    }

  }

    func presentMainScreen(){
     let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabController", bundle: nil)
      let mainTabController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
        mainTabController.selectedViewController = mainTabController.viewControllers?[1]



       //let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        //let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        //self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the name of your storyboard? Is it `MainTabController.storyboard` or `Main.storyboard`?

You are trying to load a storyboard named "`MainTabController`":

```
let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabController", bundle: nil)
```

But previously you called it Main.storyboard:

> Fiddle with the Target Membership Main.storyboard.

Also if the main tab controller is in the same storyboard as your login view controller then you can try to use this:

```
let mainTabController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your story board is named as `Main.storyboard`. `MainTabController` is the controller in the `Main` storyboard.

```
let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainTabController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
mainTabController.selectedViewController = mainTabController.viewControllers?[1]
```

Comment: thank you! after staring at it for so long it becomes easy to overlook small things like this ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabController", bundle: nil)
```

Your storyboard is named "Main"

Comment: thank you! after staring at it for so long it becomes easy to overlook small things like this ‍♂️