# My app crashes and does not change views when I tell it to

Tags: swift, xcode

My app crashes and does not change views when I tell it to. I have tried many other things but I can not get it to change programmatically for the life of me. I have attached my Workspace. Any help would be great!!!

[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GBMcfHL07gke3FVAiC3c2aumrgQYRMpH/view?usp=sharing)

This code changes the view to this

```
self.messagesController?.setupNavBarWithUser(user)
```

How do I go to this view in my storyBoard correctly.

Here is my error code

> 2018-12-17 07:56:00.777229-0500 Kind Point[7129:524001] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
> named 'MessagesController' in bundle NSBundle
> </Users/Jake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C748FA7B-1F41-49C3-8A72-F3A39E494146/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C824E34D-60DB-4CEC-8FEF-9BC939AF20C8/Kind
> Point.app> (loaded)'
> *** First throw call stack:

Comment: could you add screenshot and tell what exactly needs to do , so that directly suggest you to do.

Comment: I will add it to my original comment

Comment: "My app crashes": Any crash logs in console when it happens? What do you do when it crashes? You do an action, etc? Which methods/lines causes the crash?

Comment: update your question according to the following guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 2018-12-17 07:56:00.777229-0500 Kind Point[7129:524001] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MessagesController' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Jake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C748FA7B-1F41-49C3-8A72-F3A39E494146/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C824E34D-60DB-4CEC-8FEF-9BC939AF20C8/Kind Point.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694742/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-mainstoryboard-in-bundle-nsbundle ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496188/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-maintabcontroller-in-bundle-nsbundle ? Etc. You see that your storyboard is named "Main", not "MessagesController", so at some point you are doing it wrong.

Comment: new issue now - switch view's by running this code

 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let messagesController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesController") as! MessagesController

                self.present(messagesController, animated:true, completion:nil)

does not change successfully. "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

018-12-17 08:30:13.807999-0500 Kind Point[7975:544937] Could not cast value of type 'Kind_Point.LoginController' (0x106c5bb70) to 'Kind_Point.MessagesController' (0x106c5b908).
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using buttons, I suggest disconnecting the outlet/remove the segue from the button and re-add it.

Your terminal log says that there is no storyboard named MessagesController so, try adding a new view, or swift file and name it MessagesController. Add the messagesController to the view controller and see if it works.

To add a new view controller file to a storyboard, just copy and paste the code from one view controller and paste it to a new swift file. Then, change the name in the top of the code from ViewController, to the name of the view controller you want.